# Passing Parameters through url with slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to pass variables through the url without including ?var1=test but have that replaced with /test. I have the following code:

```
$pathinfo = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];    
$params = preg_split('|/|', $pathinfo, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($params);
```

This issue is, if I put this in the index.php file, I have to include the filename.

What I get:
http://example.com/index.php/test

What I want:
http://example.com/test

What should I do?

Comment: This is called URL rewriting. Look it up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a .htaccess file in your root folder and paste this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Just make sure mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0):

`What should I do?`

Use a rewrite rule using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html). Your rules might look like:

(example from Wordpress):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    # Existing File
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    # Existing Directory
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

More examples [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html) and some more "simple" explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

Answer (score 0):

Try create a file named `.htaccess` in your webroot with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure that modrewrite is enabled.